# unable to iterate through all the elements in the for loop

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop

I want to ssh to multiple remote server and check the raid status if it is mounted read only.

I wrote a for loop for this and the for loop is only taking the last elemnet in the list. It is not iterating from 1st elemnt, 2nd eklement and so on,

````
  for i in $(cat /home/priyashree/server.txt);do
     machine_ip=$(getent hosts $i | awk {'print $1'})
     machine_info="${i},${machine_ip}"
     machine_new_ip="$(echo ${machine_info}|cut -d, -f2)"
     echo ${machine_new_ip}
  done


 for machineip in $machine_new_ip;do
      raid_status=$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $machineip mount | grep -e '/dev/md2'| cut -d'(' -f2| cut -d, -f1) 
      echo "Raid status for machine $machine_new_ip is $raid_status"
    done```

$machine_new_ip has a list of IP as below
aa.bb.cc.dd
xx.zz.ee.ff

The 2nd for loop will only ssh to the 2nd element (xx.zz.ee.ff) in the list and the 1st element is ignored. If new IPs are added to the list the problem repeats. All the elements in the beginning are skipped only the last one is considered. Please help to correct the for loop so that it iterates over all the elements.
````

Comment: Only the last element will be used from `/home/priyashree/server.txt` because at the end of the first for `machine_new_ip` will only contain the last element's info.

Comment: /home/priyashree/server.txt has 2 server names server 1 and server 2. Also `echo ${machine_new_ip}` will give a list of 2 Ip address for server1 and server2. So the 2nd for loop should iterate over all the elements one by one,

Comment: No, the second loop iterates over `$machine_new_ip`. It has only the last value. Set in the last iteration of the previous loop.

Comment: could you please let me know why the first for loop is only taking the last element even if the file at /home/priyashree/server.txt has 2 server values server1 and server2. Why is not iterating over each elemnet

Comment: @user11549576 : You would need an array to store the machine names. But according to your _shell_ tag in your posting, you want to use Posix Shell, which does not have arrays. I suggest that you use _bash_ or _zsh_ or _ksh_.

Comment: You should try "Nagios" to check and monitor the raid status. just my 0.02$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have servers to test on so let me strip the content of the second for loop.

Problem is here `machine_new_ip="$(echo ${machine_info}|cut -d, -f2)"`

This will rewrite the variable in every cycle in the first for loop instead of creating a list for the second for loop, and you simply end up with `machine_new_ip` variable that only contain the last elemet of `/home/priyashree/server.txt` file.

Using `variable+=value` will create a list, additional space was needed to separate the values.

```
for i in $(cat /home/priyashree/server.txt);do
     machine_ip=$(getent hosts $i | awk {'print $1'})
     machine_info="${i},${machine_ip}"
     machine_new_ip+=" $(echo ${machine_info}|cut -d, -f2)"
     #echo ${machine_new_ip}
done

for machineip in $machine_new_ip;do
        echo ${machineip}
done
```

For example

```
# this is what your for cycle did:
for i in "server1" "server2";do
host="$i"
done
echo "$host"

#Output: "server2"

# -------------------

for i in "server1" "server2";do
host2+=" $i"
done
echo "$host2"

#Output: " server1 server2"
```

Comment: After amking the chnages the 2nd for loop is not iterating over the elemnts one by one. The echo statement in the 2nd for loop displays the following

Comment: I did some mistake in my answer earlier, please make sure you used the current one. I do not see what  is the second loop displayed for you.

Comment: After making the changes the 2nd for loop is not iterating over the elements one by one. The echo statement in the 2nd for loop displays the following                            Raid status for machine  aa.bb.cc.dd ee.ff.gg.hh is rw
Raid status for machine  aa.bb.cc.dd ee.ff.gg.hh is rw
 It is suppossed to display the following                                                                   Raid status for machine  aa.bb.cc.dd  is rw
Raid status for machine  ee.ff.gg.hh is rw

Comment: `echo "Raid status for machine $machine_new_ip is $raid_status"` is use `$machine_new_ip` what is contain the list of the hosts, it should be changed to `$machineip` , it is do itarate trhought the list , just wrong variable is used for display the result.

Comment: I am sorry. Did not notice the difference in the variable name. Thank for the answer. It works now,

Comment: I had one more query. Should the the elements in the list be placed horizontally separated with spaces or the elements in the list can be placed vertically in order for the for loop to work. One element in each line

Comment: for loop is see elements as they placed horizontally separated by space. So if you pass a list separated by newline for a `for var in` statement it still see it as `for i in "line1" "line2" "line3"`

Comment: therefore, placing the elements in the list horizontally separated by spaces or vertically in each line will not make a difference., For loop will still consider it as "line1" "line2" "line3"